# POST param validation in Akka HTTP

Tags: akka-http

Is it possible to validate the POST body in Akka Http?

[Case Class Validation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.3/scala/http/routing-dsl/case-class-extraction.html#Case_Class_Validation)seems to work only for get requests.

As an example:

```
case class User(name: String){
    require(name)
}
 ..... 
(post & entity(as[User])) { user =>
            complete(doSomething(user.name))
          }
```

I would like the above code to throw a ValidationRejection rejection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `require` inside scope of complete directive

```
(path("stats") & parameter("idsParam")) { idsParam =>
    complete {
      require(idsParam.length > 1)
      val ids = idsParam.split(",").map(v => CaseId(v).value)
      DBManager.getArticleStats(ids).map { case (id, stats) => IdWithValue(CaseId(id), stats) }
    }
}
```

that handles yours POST request.

And typically I have custom exception handler that wraps all exceptions into format that my API client expects such as json. `require` throws `IllegalArgumentException` so let's handle it in special way if we want to.

```
protected implicit def myExceptionHandler =
  ExceptionHandler {
    case ex: IllegalArgumentException => ctx => {
      val cause = ex.getCause
      ex.printStackTrace()
      ctx.complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, ErrorResponse(ex.code, ex))
    }
    case ex: Throwable => ctx =>
      logger.warning("Request {} could not be handled normally", ctx.request)
      ex.printStackTrace()
      ctx.complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, ErrorResponse(StatusCodes.InternalServerError.intValue, ex))
  }
```

where `ErrorResponse` is my case class that is being serialized to json using `spray-json`

Comment: Thanks. Mind sharing an example? Not quite sure how to use require inside of complete

Comment: Sure thing. Added.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't require suppose to throw ValidationRejection?

Comment: Nope, `require` is general helper function. It's not related to `akka-http` per se.

Comment: There is http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.3/scala/http/routing-dsl/case-class-extraction.html#Case_Class_Validation . But I guess it works only for GET params

Comment: For some reason ExceptionHandler is not getting called, and IllegalArgumentException is not getting cause in my Akka Route tests. Tried both explicit and implicit ExceptionHandler

Comment: Yep, but `require` is defined in `scala.Predef`.

Comment: Hmmm not sure what to say. According to this http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/http/routing-dsl/exception-handling.html it should work. Maybe `myExceptionHandler` implicit is not declared somewhere where routes are defined. You can invoke your handler explicitly via `handleExceptions` directive.